# call to a javascript function from a dynamically added html button fails when I pass params

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First I add a menu with selectable items

```
</style>
<div id='form'><select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple" onclick="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">Please select a Form type</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select></div>
```

If I chosse item number two there is some javascript code that runs and add html code dinamically to the page. As you can see there is a submit button in the html code, that calls another javascript function, which is setType();

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var foo = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var param1;
var param2;
var param3;
function myFunction(){
    if (foo)
    {
       if (foo.selectedIndex != null )
       {
           if(foo.selectedIndex>'0')
            {

                if(foo.selectedIndex == '1'){
                    //cargamos formulario 1

                    var newElement ="<div id='div1'>Advertiser ID<input type='text' name='Avertiser' value='Advertiser'><br><input type='submit' value='Submit advertiser' onClick='setType('Advertiser')';></div><div id='div2'>Offer: <input type='text' name='Offer' value='Offer'><br><input type='submit' value='Submit Offer'></div><div id='div3'>Date: <input type='text' name='Date' value='Date'><br><input type='submit' value='Submit Date'></div>";
                    var bodyElement = document.body;
                    bodyElement.innerHTML = newElement + bodyElement.innerHTML;
                    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("" );
                //  ("Advertiser Id: <input type='text' name='AD' value='AD'><br><input type='submit' value='SubmitAD'>Offer: <input type='text' name='Offer' value='Offer'><br><input type='submit' value='SubmitOffer'>Date: <input type='text' name='Date' value='Date'><br><input type='submit' value='Date'>");                    
                }
                if(foo.selectedIndex == '2'){
                    //cargamos formulario 2

                }
                if(foo.selectedIndex == '3'){
                    //cargamos formulario 3

                }
           }
       } 
    }
}
```

My problem is I want to pass the Advertiser Value as a param into this javascript function, to store it in a global variable, and when the three submit buttons params are in their variable, then make an ajax call to another file. My problem is when I call the javascript function with the param, it doesn't run. Without params works. I don't understand the problem.

```
function setType(id){
    alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: "Advertiser Value as a param into this javascript function" - which function? myFunction()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your "" :) `'setType('Advertiser')'` is bad code, try

```
onClick="setType('Advertiser')"
```

and in HTML ALWAYS use `""` in atributes, not `''`!!!

Comment: Both  `”` and `’` are valid to quote attribute values in html, but `”` is more common.

Answer (score 0):

This `'setType('Advertiser')'` won't work, try `'setType(\"Advertiser\")'`

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwcs3d6o/)